# Getting text between quotes in something already found by a Regex

Tags: regex, shell, unix, grep

I'v got in my templating system (Twig) for localized strings, items like these:

```
{{ "I'd like this quote to be localized" | trans }}
{{ "this_is_a_key" |trans}}
{{'another text'| trans}}
{{"ohter"|trans }}
{{'no_spaces'|trans}}
```

With this command:

`find src/ -type f -name '*.twig' -execdir egrep -o -- "\{\{[^|()}{]*\|[(trans) ^}]*\}\}" {} \;`

I'm able to locate all these in my various template file, witch is already great.

But I'd like to go a bit further, and directly fetch what is between "" or '' in my above examples. How to customize my search or do another search after to extract that?

PS: My current .sh script is:

```
old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
transFound = 0;

allUsed=`find src/ -type f -name '*.twig' -execdir egrep -o -- "\{\{[^|(){]*\|[(trans) ^}]*\}\}" {} \;`
defaultFile="messages.yml"

for key in $allUsed
    do
        echo $key
        let "transfound++"
    done

echo "Found $transfound translations"
```

Comment: Maybe I should use | sed 'pattern' but don't know how..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it ;) Had to use sed:

```
find src/ -type f -name '*.twig' -execdir egrep -o -- "\{\{ ?['\"][^|()}{]*\|[(trans) ^}]*\}\}" {} \; | sed "s/.*'\(.*\)'[^']*$/\1/" | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)"[^"]*$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perl`(**-P**) regex, and `only`(**-o**) print out match

```
$ grep -oP "(['\"]).*\1" input.txt
"I'd like this quote to be localized"
"this_is_a_key"
'another text'
"ohter"
'no_spaces'
```

---

```
   -o, --only-matching
          Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

   -P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression (PCRE, see below).  This is highly experimental  and  grep  -P  may  warn  of  unimplemented
          features.
```